# SQL query comparing an attribute in multiple tuples based on values of another attribute within the relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I just made this post a little while ago:
[SQL query concerning the sum of occurrences for multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33513209/5446245)

The table below is the same but with a slight modification:

```
                    Test

    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  Name  |  Date  |Location| Score  |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | Steven |03-05-12| 120000 |   78   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | James  |04-09-11| 110000 |   67   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | James  |06-22-11| 110000 |   58   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  Ryan  |10-11-13| 250000 |   62   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  Ryan  |12-19-13| 180000 |   95   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Essentially, I need a query to select the names of people who have taken multiple tests and gotten a lower score the next time.

For example, it would select James but not Ryan because he got a higher score the second time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
FROM test AS a 
JOIN test AS b 
  ON a.name = b.name 
 AND a.date > b.date 
 AND a.score < b.score
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16cf2/1/0)