# SQL Query comparing several tuples (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently posted this question: [SQL query comparing an attribute in multiple tuples based on values of another attribute within the relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514149/sql-query-comparing-an-attribute-in-multiple-tuples-based-on-values-of-another-a)

The table below is the same but with a slight modification:

```
                    Test

    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  Name  |  Date  |Location| Score  |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | Steven |03-05-12| 120000 |   78   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | James  |04-09-11| 110000 |   67   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | James  |06-22-11| 110000 |   58   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  Ryan  |10-11-13| 250000 |   62   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  Ryan  |12-19-13| 180000 |   55   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  Ryan  |01-20-15| 180000 |   99   |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Notice that Ryan's score decreases but then increases later. The response that I previously received still selects Ryan in this case despite his scores not always increasing. I understand I might not have been clear in my original post, but is there any query I could do to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry, I posted this very quickly.

Essentially I need a query to select the names of all of the people who got lower scores every consecutive test they attempted.

ie, not accept Ryan, but accept James

Comment: can you then combine the two questions, go back to that one. And re-jigger your Accepted Answer accordingly. Instead of dupes. We now have 3 variations on the theme. 3 questions

Comment: also, make it clear that it is definitely mysql and not Sql Server (or whatever the case is). A guy wrote up a Sql Server answer with `partition` because some find `sql` to mean Sql Server

Comment: Although it's unfortunate that the OP has had trouble figuring out how to pose the question he *really* wanted answered, it would be poor form for him to go back and fundamentally change his others after accepting answers to them.

Comment: I do not notice that Ryan score decreases but then increases later!!! also be clear in which cases Ryan must be in or out the output

Comment: I agree @JohnBollinger

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think is OK he make another question when more information is add and that change the question. But OP please make it a FULL question not make us go following bread crumps to know the details

Comment: Sorry about that @LuisSiquot. Edited

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the question is in the Edit. I apologize

Comment: @sampleton, what about Steven -- should he be selected?  He (trivially) did not take any test on which he scored better than a previous test.

Comment: @JohnBollinger no he should not be, because he never took multiple tests

Comment: in a variable set (mysql variables), with `order by name,date`, the @grp variable for Steven would not change from the previous one once Steven is reached and then proceeding. So Steven would not have a chance for his non-existing 2nd row to have a lower score. Thus Steven does not make the resultset. In the real-world, one would not use `name` but rather an `id` of course, unless you can have only one Steven

Comment: what about steven? he only have one test, is he in or out?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the two comments above say no

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
This is a complete replacement for my original, wrong, answer.

The problem is complicated by the fact that you want to simultaneously select for two very different criteria:

1. The person has multiple rows in table `Test`, and
2. Every row for a given person and date has a lesser score than is recorded for the same person on every earlier date

The fact that you are comparing different rows of the same table suggests approaching the problem via a self-join:

```
FROM
  Test t1
  join Test t2
    on t1.Name = t2.Name
```

If we filter out the results arising from joining each row to itself, then that leaves only rows pertaining to people who are referenced by multiple rows.  Moreover, for rows R1 and R2 both with the same `Name`, we only need to consider one of the pairs (R1, R2) and (R2, R1).  We can address both of those considerations with a single filter:

```
WHERE t1.Date < t2.Date
```

We want to perform an analysis of the joined result on a `Name`-by-`Name` basis; that suggests an aggregate query (if suitable aggregate functions are available):

```
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

We want only those *aggregates* that satisfy our criteria, and those criteria are that every row that passed the `WHERE` filter, and therefore has `t1.Date < t2.Date`, also has `t1.Score > t2.Score`.  We can rely here on the fact that relational operators evaluate to a number: `1` for true, and `0` for false.  If we add those values across each group, we can determine whether every row satisfied the criterion:

```
HAVING SUM(t1.Score > t2.Score) = COUNT(*)
```

Given that we want to select only the names (which are conveniently already distinct, courtesy of the grouping), that all comes together as

```
SELECT t1.Name
FROM
  Test t1
  join Test t2
    on t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t1.Date < t2.Date
GROUP BY t1.Name
HAVING SUM(t1.Score > t2.Score) = COUNT(*)
```

Here's a fiddle, with sample data drawn from the question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dcba/16/0

Comment: Updated with a completely revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think John answer is great but I want add some information.

Using this base query **[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/489cb/18)** here you can include all the conditionals in the `left join`

```
select t1.Name, t1.Date, t1.Score, t2.Date, t2.Score
from
  student t1
  left join student t2 
         on t1.Name = t2.Name
        and t1.Date < t2.Date
        and t1.Score <= t2.Score

|   Name |                       Date | Score |                      Date |  Score |
|--------|----------------------------|-------|---------------------------|--------|
|   Ryan |  October, 11 2013 00:00:00 |    62 | January, 20 2015 00:00:00 |     99 |
|   Ryan | December, 19 2013 00:00:00 |    55 | January, 20 2015 00:00:00 |     99 |
| Steven |    March, 05 2012 00:00:00 |    78 |                    (null) | (null) |
|  James |    April, 09 2011 00:00:00 |    67 |                    (null) | (null) |
|  James |     June, 22 2011 00:00:00 |    58 |                    (null) | (null) |
|   Ryan |  January, 20 2015 00:00:00 |    99 |                    (null) | (null) |
```

Then you can use a conditional `SUM` to find how many times each name increase his score. In this case `Ryan` will be `2`

```
select t1.Name, SUM(IF(t2.Date IS NULL, 0, 1)) as increase_score
from
  student t1
  left join student t2 
         on t1.Name = t2.Name
        and t1.Date < t2.Date
        and t1.Score <= t2.Score
GROUP BY t1.Name
HAVING 
    increase_score = 0                    -- not increase score in any test
and count(*) > 1                          -- present more than one test
```

Comment: All I know is this: yours returns James, and John's Answer returns Steven. And I had to read both questions (this one and prior) from Op to come up with this: Students that only have continuously decreasing grades. And I would move mountains before i use a `NOT IN`. I think the answer is James. And the OP needs to know how to write a question without cookie crumbs scattered as someone said

Comment: @Drew Thanks have to fix it after read again the comment to remove the ones didnt present more than one test.  The good part is easy to change if want those include it agan.

Comment: well the results you are getting are the ones I expect.  :)